# creating a new column of increments with respect to the value in another column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have a table

```
CustomerID  Country
1   Germany
6   Germany
17  Germany
25  Germany
32  USA
36  USA
39  Germany
43  USA
44  Germany
```

And I wanna make a new column which indicates the appearance with respect to Country

```
CustomerID  Country  Count
1           Germany    1
6           Germany    2
17          Germany    3
25          Germany    4
32            USA      1
36            USA      2
39          Germany    5
43            USA      3
44          Germany    6
```

How to write it in SQL

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by country order by CustomerID) as counter
from t;
```

In earlier versions, there are multiple methods.  One is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.country = t.country and
              t2.CustomerID <= t.CustomerID
       ) as counter
from t;
```

Comment: For second version, the count() will take the whole set rather than for each country. Is that correct?

Comment: @Kimmi . . . No.  It should produce an incrementing sequence.